# Writing PID File on Linux

Tags: c, linux, centos, daemon

I am currently working on a linux daemon that needs to be single instance (i.e restricted to 1 user 1 process). What would be the best way of doing so without having to use `getpid()` to manually write the pid out to */var/run/* and then lock it using `flock()`?

Comment: You don't have to write a pid file, but you will have to use some kind of lock file.

Comment: The advantage of writing the PID is that you can check to see if the process is actually alive and well too...

Comment: @awoodland: No, you cannot. A pid is useless except to the process's direct parent, which can ensure that the pid is not reused until a successful call to a `wait`-family function. Any other use leads to race conditions, false-positives that a process still exists, and even a danger of signalling the wrong process.

Comment: If you want to check that the process is still alive, you can have your daemon open and hold a lock on a file. When it terminates, the lock will automatically be relinquished, and there is no race condition. The same can also be accomplished with unix sockets, robust mutexes, and perhaps several other similar mechanisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just lock the executable file itself.

Comment: Would not it restrict it to whole system as single instance? Ie. 2 different users cannot have their own instance on single system then?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the start-up and shut-down with [start-stop-daemon](http://man.cx/start-stop-daemon(8)).

Answer (score 1):

Just use [libunique](http://live.gnome.org/LibUnique). It is the simplest way.

Comment: That looked really interesting, but it seems like it's heavily tied to GNOME unless I missed something?

Comment: It depends on GTK, not Gnome. It is difficult to find Linux desktop without GTK. However, if you are going to use your daemon on a headless server, libunique isn't the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this in a couple of initd scripts I've written.  Replace the COMMAND with whatever you need

```
PIDFILE=/var/run/service.pid
COMMAND="java -jar start.jar"
$COMMAND > /dev/null 2>&1 &
echo $! > $PIDFILE
```

Edited with @dogane 's suggestion, tested as well.

Comment: $! will give you the process id. You don't need to grep ps.

Comment: This fails, and is a classic race condition.  There is no guarantee that only one instance of COMMAND will be running.

Comment: Admittedly this is only a partial answer to his question, it shows how to write the pid file.  I use this as a start up script which is used along side a init script which actually checks if the process is already running.  I'll post that code tonight when I have time if @Error1f1f hasn't already moved on.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't have a lock file, use a socket instead. Another instance won't be able to start up because the address will already be in use.

Comment: I think you mean bind a socket.